# Casperjs sendKeys not working

Tags: web-scraping, casperjs

I have this code to fill an input, I can get input attributes yet I can't set the value, could anybody help me either if it's with other library please.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start();

casper
  .then(function(){
    console.log("Start:");
  })
  .thenOpen("https://alsea.interfactura.com/RegistroDocumento.aspx?opc=Starbucks")
  .then(function(){
     casper.sendKeys('#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTienda', '12345');


    this.echo(this.getElementAttribute('input[type="text"][id="ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTienda"]', 'value'));
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: You can evaluate a JavaScript code to fill that input.

Comment: Thanks, as dasmelch says the input value is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sendKeys() work in your case. If you do a screenshot you see that the form element is filled with the value you set:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start("https://alsea.interfactura.com/RegistroDocumento.aspx?opc=Starbucks");
casper.then(function() {
  casper.sendKeys('#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTienda', '12345');
});
casper.then(function() {
  casper.capture("test.png");
  this.echo(this.getElementAttribute('input[type="text"][id="ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTienda"]', 'value'));
});
casper.run();
```

Probably the value is set is saved somewhere else on this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as you mention value is stored somewhere else, as it is a big company I guess they try to protect from doing this. Actually, I don't need to read the value since I validated inputs are filling so thank you very much I'll keep going so if everything is ok, I'll get an email from the website.